# list elements in a for loop in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
a = ['1','2','3']
```

My code:

```
result=[]
for item in a:
    if item == '1': # 1
        result.append(item)
    else:
        result.append('haha')
```

But it doesn't work. What can I do? I get:

```
result = ['haha', 'haha', 'haha']
```

I want:

```
result = ['1', 'haha', 'haha']
```

Comment: __append method - Add an item to the end of the list__ http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: It doesn't work because your indenting  isn't correct. Please consult a tutorial, or if you are, possibly a better one.

Comment: i suspect this isn't only about the wrong indentation. can you post a small, complete chunk of code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Marcin I think it can't just be the indentation that is wrong. The indentation would cause the code to fail to compile rather than to act incorrectly.

Comment: Works for me but I'd prefer a list comprehension : `result = [item if item == '1' else 'haha' for item in a]`

Comment: @Dunes The behaviour is described as "it doesn't work" which is quite apt to cover syntax errors. Note that Python does not have a separate compilation phase with most (all complete?) implementations.

Comment: @Marcin my interpretation was that ANSIC had generated the first result (so compilation wasn't an issue). You might be interested to know that python can take `.pyc` files and just run them without compiling and that there exists the module/program `py_compile` (in the standard library) that will compile a file without executing it.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct, the result is as expected (see here: http://ideone.com/ZZpPW).

The problem may be one of the below:

1. Your code is different that the one you have posted.
2. `a` is not `['1', '2', '3']`, but eg. `[1, 2, 3]` (`1` integer is not equal to `'1'` string).

Comment: Thank you, problem solving, sloppy! ideone.com collection

Comment: Please don't forget to accept answers you find useful. Accept them by clicking the grey arrow beneath the answer score box

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be a one-line list expression:

`result = [ x if x == "1" else "haha" for x in a ]`

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is wrong. It should be -

```
for item in a:
    if item == '1':
        result.append(item)
    else:
        result.append('haha')
```

To make 'if' statement part of 'for', you should indent it as above.

Comment: This is exactly how OP's question looks to me. Care to correct you answer?

Comment: Thank you, problem solving, sloppy!

Comment: @Tadeck Do you think what you see is OP's original post? He has edited(corrected) it after my post. For confirmation see the above comment from him.

Comment: @theharshest: The original revision is visible [here](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10681744/1), but the code was obviously incomplete or incorrectly indented during the question formatting. You can see this by trying to execute the code from the first revision ([like here](http://ideone.com/vqoH3)) - it will give you SyntaxError instead of incorrect result. He posted similar comment to my answer, so I would not assume it meant your answer solved his problems ;)